# How to use MiscUtil.Operator on System.Byte?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm using [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) Operators for a while without any big problems. But now i found something that really bothers me:

```
byte first = 13;
byte second = 29;

byte result = MiscUtil.Operator.Add(first, second);
```

The simple expected result of this equation should be `result == 42` but unfortunately this throws an `InvalidOperationException`:

```
The binary operator Add is not defined for the types 'System.Byte' and 'System.Byte'.
```

By taking a closer look at this odd behavior you'll find out that `System.Byte` really doesn't implement these operators. Within C# these types will be implicitly converted to an `Int32` and that does implement these operators.

So the question is now: Is there any chance to get MiscUtil to work with `byte` and `sbyte`?

Comment: Careful what you wish for.  This is not supported by Expression.Add() because of the great odds for undiagnosable overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, `int` etc *also* don't implement these operators. They are not provided by "operators" in the normal sense (which would involve a static-`call`), but represented directly by the `add` op-code. Ultimately, the failure in this case is actually coming from the `Expression` API:

```
var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(byte));
var y = Expression.Parameter(typeof(byte));
var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<byte,byte,byte>>(
    Expression.Add(x,y), x, y).Compile(); // explodes here
```

To *fix* it, MiscUtil would have to special-case the `byte`/`sbyte` versions; something like:

```
var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(byte));
var y = Expression.Parameter(typeof(byte));
var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<byte,byte,byte>>(
    Expression.Convert(
        Expression.Add(
            Expression.Convert(x, typeof(int)),
            Expression.Convert(y, typeof(int))
         ),typeof(byte)), x, y).Compile();
```

However! It has been a long time since I knew my keys for Jon's repo ;p

Oddly enough, though, it isn't all that hard to implement the entire thing in raw IL... I actually stumbled into (on a USB-drive) a very old .NET 2.0 (i.e. before `Expression`) version of "generic operators" that I wrote many many years ago, which might do the job. Or easier: just patch MiscUtil locally to handle `byte`/`sbyte`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Marc's answer i patched my local version of MiscUtil. Withing the *ExpressionUtil.cs* file i applied the following patch:

```
Index: ExpressionUtil.cs
===================================================================
--- ExpressionUtil.cs
+++ ExpressionUtil.cs
@@ -68,6 +68,18 @@
             {
                 try
                 {
+                    if (typeof(TArg1) == typeof(byte)
+                       || typeof(TArg1) == typeof(sbyte)
+                       || typeof(TArg2) == typeof(byte)
+                       || typeof(TArg2) == typeof(sbyte))
+                    {
+                        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TArg1, TArg2, TResult>>(
+                            Expression.Convert(body(
+                                    Expression.Convert(lhs, typeof(int)),
+                                    Expression.Convert(rhs, typeof(int))
+                                 ), typeof(TResult)), lhs, rhs).Compile();
+                    }
+
                     return Expression.Lambda<Func<TArg1, TArg2, TResult>>(body(lhs, rhs), lhs, rhs).Compile();
                 }
                 catch (InvalidOperationException)
```

So maybe one shiny day the *official version* will be updated, or anyone who needs it can take it from here and locally apply the patch.